# Xamarin.Forms Azure Mobile App Services Offline Sync without hosting Web Api on Azure

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services

At the moment I have an app that uses Azure Mobile App Services to manage offline sync as well as authentiation. Authentication is done with Azure Active Directory and the way that I have it setup is that the web api is published as an app service on azure and it is configured as an app in the Active Directory Section. The Native App which is done in Xamarin.Forms is also configured in azure so that whenever the app makes a request it can properly authenticate with the api.

What I want to do now is take this web api and put it in an on-premise server. I have to do this in order to optimize some latency issues that I am having when retrieving data. My question is how can I use the offline sync functionality with the api in and on-premise server while still using Azure Active Directory as my authenticator.

Where I am mostly having issues is with the authentication part of the implementation.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you are using [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) for build-in authentication without having to change code on the app backend. `Authentication / Authorization for Azure App Service` (Easy Auth) is implemented as a native IIS module that runs on Azure side, details you could follow [Architecture of Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization](http://cgillum.tech/2016/02/01/architecture-of-azure-app-service-authentication-authorization/).

> My question is how can I use the offline sync functionality with the api in and on-premise server while still using Azure Active Directory as my authenticator.

AFAIK, we could not install the native IIS module `easyauth.dll`. Based on your scenario, you need to do some additional work to achieve your purpose.

For .NET backend, you could use [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication/) OWIN middleware to validate tokens (the JWT authenticationToken). **Note:** This middle-ware is used to local development and debugging the mobile app .net server on your side.

- For [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow) flow

  You need to add a additional endpoint in your app backend for receiving the `access_token` returned by AAD to the client user, then your app backend would use the access token to access the signed-in user endpoint (e.g. https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6) to retrieve the user basic info, then encode user info into a JWT token and return to your client. Here is an example for generating the JWT token, you could refer to [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#custom-auth).

  **Note:** The App Service build-in authentication would also generate the JWT authenticationToken to the mobile client. For this approach, you retrieve the signed-in user information manually and follow the [custom-auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#custom-auth) to generate the token by yourself.
- For [Server-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow) flow

  You need to provide a login endpoint and redirect the user the AD authorization endpoint, then your app backend receive the authorization_code and retrieve the access_token, then access signed-in user info via the access_token, then encode the user claims to JWT authenticationToken and redirect the token (e.g. `https://{your-domain}/.auth/login/done#token={the-json-string-of-LoginResult}`) to the client user.

**Note:** The above two approaches are used to implement some similar features from Easy Auth in your on-premise server.

Moreover, you could just use the middlewares **UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication** for AAD v1.0 endpoint or **UseOAuthBearerAuthentication** for AAD v2.0 endpoint to project your web API instead of the authentication middleware provided by Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication. Here are some tutorials, you could follow them:

[Azure AD .NET Web API getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet)

[Secure an MVC web API with AAD v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-dotnet-api)

For this approach, your mobile client could leverage the ADAL or MSAL client library for acquiring the token. Then when you implement the `MobileServiceClient` instance, you could specific a custom [DelegatingHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler(v=vs.110).aspx) for adding the authorization header with the value to the access token you acquired as the bearer token against your Web API backend. Details you could follow the **How to: Customize request headers** section under [Working with the client SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library).